# how to debug chrome extension downloaded from chrome store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to debug a chrome extension downloaded from chrome store. is it possible and how.
I have readium chrome extension and it is not working properly. I want to know why.
Thanks

Comment: The extension, [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) will allow you to download the extension source without the need to install the extension. This will allow you to take a look at the code prior to installing a extension and may make it easier for you to debug (and actually fix) the extension.  You will need to determine the licensing for the extension in order to see if you have the right to create a derivative work (i.e. one with the bug fixes).

Answer (score 1):

If the extension run front-end scripts: right click on the page, `Inspect` > `Sources` tab > `Content scripts` tab. Then you can select the Chrome extension that not work correctly and add a breakpoint for example.

If the extension run back-end scripts: Go to this url: [chrome://extensions](http://chrome://extensions) then scroll to your extension and click on background page button. A popup will be opened and you can go to the `sources` tab and debug the script.